# Finding intermediate colours between two xyY colour points

Tags: algorithm, graphics, colors

I am working in an application where I need to know the intermediate points between two xy coordinates in CIE 1931 colour space.

In the picture below we can see that a linear transition (straight line) between A and B will go through a series of other colours, and I am struggling to find a mathematical way of describing the transitions between A and B.

Any ideas?

[image: CIE 1931 colour space - image from wikipedia]

Comment: What are you actually looking for? A parameterized formula for linear interpolation? Values in another color space for a linear XYZ transition? XYZ values for a transition that's linear in another color space?

Comment: I am looking for a formula to get colour points between any two points in XY colour space

Comment: Well then, the fact that you're dealing with colors is irrelevant then. It's just a mater of parameterizing segment A-B in your illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your problem correctly, it's just a matter of finding a parameterization of a point on segment A-B in your illustration. The fact that it is a color is irrelevant.

Let *C* with coordinates (Xc,Yc) be such a point.
Then C can be written as:

```
Xc = Xa + a * (Xb-Xa)
Yc = Ya + a * (Yb-Ya)
```

where *a* is a fractional number in the range [0 ; 1]